# How to copy files into the unit test bundle?

Tags: ios, swift, assert, xctest

I want to add assert eventually in my test cases. I am following the below link.
https://github.com/ketzusaka/xctest-assert-eventually#static-linking
How to do the copying files into unit test bundle mentioned under *Static linking*?

Comment: You just need to drag and drop the files inside KZAssertEventuall in your Unit Tests target/folder. But it's not necessary if you installed it already via cocoapods.

Comment: ok @TitouandeBailleul